# ubuntu: ssh: connect to host ubuntu port 22: Connection refused

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-16.04

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Hadoop 3.3.1
I have mannually downloaded and installed java version "1.8.0_261"
when I run start-dfs.sh,

> hadoop@ubuntu:~/hadoop/sbin$ start-dfs.sh
> Starting namenodes on [ubuntu]
> ubuntu: ssh: connect to host ubuntu port 22: Connection refused
> Starting datanodes
> localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
> Starting secondary namenodes [ubuntu]
> ubuntu: ssh: connect to host ubuntu port 22: Connection refused
> 2021-06-25 17:42:19,711 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... > using builtin-java classes where applicable

Answer (score 0):

Try installing whole SSH package pack:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

Comment: Unclear how this fixes a connection refusal. SSH was already installed

Comment: @OneCricketeer,after install ssh,'Connection refused error' is missing,but still have 'Permission denied' error

Comment: Sounds like you've fixed that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68129310/hadoop-starting-namenodes-on-ubuntu-ubuntu-permission-denied-publickey-passw#comment120460135_68129310